# ¿como accedo a un elemento no estático a través de mi método estático, pero necesito que sea el mismo y no uno nuevo?

Tags: c#

Quiero introducir dentro del datasource una lista que retorno de mi data acces, pero el método de donde quiero acceder a mi elemento aspx es estático.

Lo intente de la siguiente forma:

```
CreateOnlineTest create=new CreateOnlineTest ();
create.dropListEdit.DataSource=retornoQuestions.List;
create.dropListEdit.DataBind();
```

Pero si lo hago de esa forma crea un nuevo objeto y por ende nuevos atributos y me da como resultado null en `dropListEdit`, lo que necesito es llenar el combo que tengo actualmente y no referenciarlo a uno nuevo mediante la función estática, lo intente con this pero no se puede usar en métodos estáticos.

Comment: puedes pasar como parámetro a tu método el elemento que deseas modificar

Comment: Te seviria Singleton?